# CodeIgniter add to cart error 404

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, codeigniter

I am currently trying to do a project based on a YouTube tutorial building a shopping cart but whenever I click the add to cart button I keep getting error 404: page not found.

product view

```
<div class="col-md-4 product">
    <div class="product-price"><?php echo $product->price; ?></div>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>products/details/<?php echo $product->id; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/<?php echo $product->image; ?>" />
        </a>
        <div class="product-name"><br>
            <?php echo $product->name; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="product-add">
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?> cart/add">
                QTY: <input class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $product->id; ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $product->price; ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $product->name; ?>"/>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add To Cart</button>
            </form>

        </div>          
</div>
```

product controller

```
<?php
class Products extends CI_Controller{
public function index(){
    //get all products
    $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->get_products();

    //load view
    $data['main_content'] = 'products';
    $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
}

public function details($id){
    //get product details from the model
    $data['product'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($id);

    //load view
    $data['main_content'] = 'details';
    $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
}
}
```

Comment: The url of your add to cart button probably doesn't have corresponding name in you controller.

Comment: My best guess is that the page isn't found.

Comment: Very hard to help with out seeing some code in your question. You can re edit your question by clicking on the edit button.

Comment: I've added the code added that I think is causing the issue.

Comment: You may need to set some routes up https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples also you may need to include the index.php in url `http://localhost/projectname/index.php/controller/function/some_id`

Comment: Make sure you have set the base url also. `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourprojectname/';`

Comment: Do you mean I need to include the index in the base url?

Comment: try to use index.php  If you never configured base url then ok .directly use site_url function also you have to add your model file to post

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I managed to get it working in the end.

Answer (score 0):

add following codes

**application/config/ruotes.php**

```
$route['cart/add'] = 'products/addtocart';
```

**Product Controller** - update

```
<?php
class Products extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index(){
        //get all products
        $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->get_products();

        //load view
        $data['main_content'] = 'products';
        $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
    }
    public function details($id){
        //get product details from the model
        $data['product'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($id);

        //load view
        $data['main_content'] = 'details';
        $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
    }   
    public function addtocart(){
        // here you can collect submitted product values such as item_number, price, name

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_POST);        
    }
}
```